# How to extract the text before and after matching the pattern in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to extract the text before and after matching the pattern inside a file using Python

Comment: Its a bit too broad, please post your input and expected output and the code you tried so far.

Comment: My matched line looks like:

Entity {‘entity_class’: ‘Hardware Entities (AHV)’, ‘entity_model’: ‘13G Firmware Payload (el6)’} has available versions [{‘entity_class’: ‘Hardware Entities (AHV)’,“entity_model”: “PT Agent on AHV (el6)”}]’

In this, I want to extract the text before "has available versions" into one variable/file and the text after  "has available versions" into other one.

I tried to extract this line from logfile using the below code:

txt="has available versions"
search=open("file_name")
for line in search:
  if txt in line:
    print(line)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? You want to split a string by a value?

```
with open("filename.extension",'r') as file:
    txt = "has available versions"
    for line in file:
        if txt in line:
            part_one = line.split(txt)[0]
            part_two = line.split(txt)[1]
```

You could put your values into a dictionary:

```
import re

dict = {}
l = "[{'entity_class':'some value','value1':'1', 'value2':'2', 'entity_model':'some_value', 'value 3': '3'}]"
list = l.split(",")
for entry in list:
    key = entry.split(":")[0]
    value = entry.split(":")[1]
    key = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', key)
    value = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', value)
    dict[key] = value
print(dict)
```

Comment: Yes.
Need some enhancement out of it.
How can I extract the individual values out of it. Suppose like if want only ‘Hardware Entities (AHV)’  which is associated with "entity_class" in part_one/part_two ?
Here the value associated with entity_class may vary other than 'Hardware Entities (AHV)'

Comment: You could just split the beginning and the end of the part you want. For example line.split("{")[1].split(",")[0]) in this case. There are a ton of different ways to accomplish what you want depending on the exact input you use.

Comment: Or by string indexing: print(line[line.find('‘entity_class')::].split(",")[0]) What I do here is find the index position of 'entity_class' and display the string from the start of this position to the end. Afterwards I split until I encounter a ","

Comment: Looking out for other ways, than using split indices. Because the number of variables inside it keeps varying. Here in the case I specified it's just two values.

Could be better, if the matching pattern is based on the string value as I need because I may need to extract some other values also.

Comment: For the second way I suggested that shouldnt matter, since you search specifically for a name there. But it kinda looks like you should create a python dictionary with the keys and values in the string.

Comment: Let's say, one of my line has data like

[{'entity_class':'some value','value1':'1', 'value2':'2', 'entity_model':'some_value', 'value 3': '3'}]


And other line have some data like above and number of entities may be less/more.

If I use slicing it's difficult to search.

Comment: I actually think splitting is one of the easiest ways to do it. I wrote some code to put the combinations into a dictionary. Easier to access that way.

Comment: Even i'm thinking the same, i'm trying to convert into dict.

Comment: I converted the str into dict by using json.loads() function. I'm getting the below error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)